# Memory & repeated Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I recently wrote a function to repeatedly call a function (that returns a promise) until it succeeds.  My first thought was to do it like this:

```
//Takes a function that returns a Promise
static promiseKeepTrying(func) {

  const callFunc = () => {
    return func()
      .catch(() => {
        return this.promiseTimeout(5000)
          .then(() => callFunc())
      })
  }

  return callFunc()
}

static promiseTimeout(time) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time, time))
}
```

But I worried that each new call is creating a new Promise linked to the previous one, resulting in memory (slowly) being consumed.  Is that right?

So I went with this implementation:

```
//Takes a function that returns a Promise
static promiseKeepTrying(func) {

  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    const callFunc = () => {
      func()
        .then(results => {
          resolve(results)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          setTimeout(callFunc, 5000)
        })
    }

    callFunc()
  })
}
```

I think this one would not consume memory for each retry.  Is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is no active reference to the Promise and it either completed or was rejected, garbage collection takes care for it and relases memory.

Comment: @Zydnar `func` is a function returning a promise that may resolve or reject, so the usage of `.then().catch()` is ordinary. There's no guarantee it's always going to resolve

Comment: @Klaycon Ok, but there is no need to use sleep functionality.

Comment: @Zydnar, how do you propose the OP waits before a retry?

Comment: Ok, I see where it's heading - first it would be nice to see what actually func() does.

Comment: I think the first formulation is fine and doesn't produce any uncollected garbage, even in a long chain of fails and retries.  (nothing is retained by the catches).  The second formulation doesn't change much other than wrapping in an unnecessary first promise.

Comment: This is what I thougt at first, since func is already async, there is no gain in wrapping it in parent promise just the opposite.

Comment: Now it's clear this question should be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since it's working code

Comment: @Zydnar Disagree, the question contains a clear technical question dealing with the inner workings of javascript promises and memory management. The answer seems like it'd be rather interesting and useful, I can't find any easy to digest resources about how promises work internally.

Comment: It's clear and all, but it more belongs to codereview than anywhere else.

Comment: @Zydnar The question would be closed as off-topic on codereview as it is not asking for code improvements. It is perfectly on-topic here as it asks a clear technical question with an answer that can be sourced from canonical resources and source code.

Comment: Yes it is asking for code improvement regarding memory usage.

Comment: @Zydnar would you be comfortable switching to Async Await?

Comment: @Zydnar your second bit of code avoids the promise of a constantly-increasing chain of promises.

Comment: @TKoL async await it's just syntax at lower level it's the same. I'm personally not a big fan of async await since some developers put await in places where code could run just fine without waiting for it.

Comment: @TKoL my code??? I haven't provided any code.

Comment: Sure, at lower level it's "the same", but you can express retrying a function that returns a promise much more succinctly with it. It would look much simpler and be more easy to understand to someone new looking at your code

Comment: @Zydnar my bad I thought you were OP

Answer (score 0):

Your second implementation does indeed avoid the constantly-increasing stack of promises, so will avoid that memory leak.

If you wanted to do something similar with async/await, you could do:

```
async function promiseKeepTrying(func) {
  let result;
  let tries = 0;

  while (!result) {
    try {
      result = await func();
      return result;
    } catch(e) {
      tries++;
      // here, optionally you can throw after, say, 20 tries.
    }
  }
}
```